# Doctrine install fails on laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm, doctrine, laravel-6

I'm totally new to Laravel and doctrine, as starting I choose Laravel 6 and go through some tutorials. As I see it's better to use Doctrine with Laravel, then I tried to install Doctrine to my project, but unfortunately, it is getting failed.

Is it because that Laravel 6 is new and not yet supporting Doctrine? or what I'm doing wrong?

I tried this command on composer

```
composer require "laravel-doctrine/orm:1.3.*"
```

It gives me some errors like

[image]

Then, I tried to follow Laravel documentation for version 6.x and found in database section it has mentioned to install doctrine/dbal Before modifying a column

> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency
>   to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to
>   determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries
>   needed to make the specified adjustments to the column:
>
> composer require doctrine/dbal

But, this command also lead me to the same error.

Please guide me through the correct path. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are installing the wrong version of the package. The GitHub page of the package has a section "[Versions](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm#versions)" where available versions and their respective Laravel versions are listed:.

The version you are installing is `1.3.*`, which is for Laravel 5.4. Since you want a version for Laravel 6, you should use

```
composer require "laravel-doctrine/orm:1.5.*"
```

Comment: Been awhile since I installed Laravel but composer is pretty good at determining correct versions.  I suspect it will work just fine without any version being specified.

Comment: True. You could leave out the version number, but specifically for Laravel 6 OP should use version 1.5. If Laravel >6 is released and no version number is given this would still work for Laravel 6